# How to edit interface in typescript?

Tags: typescript, gun

I fixed a type error when adding custom functions to the gun chain by adding `bind():any` under `IGunChainReference` in `@types/gun/index.ts`. How can I add move this to one of my project files?

I could not find any answers online except to use `interface ... extends ...` which wouldn't
`interface IGunChainReference extends IGunChainReference` does not work, as it is a loop.

In other words:

How can I change change the types after they are declared?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn about the rules of the site as well as [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think I might have solved it with

```
interface CustomChain extends IGunChainReference {
  bind(): any
}
let gun: CustomChain = GUN<AppState>(['https://gun-manhattan.herokuapp.com/gun'])
```